# Pagination, Filter and Sorting on dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, sorting, pagination, datatables, dynamic-tables

I am creating a table dynamically and data in the table are set after an Ajax call done. I have tried DataTable JS to implement three feature on dynamically created table namely - Pagination, Sorting and filtering. But am I not able to do it.

Could any one suggest any way to do it out? Please suggest it as a working example because I am novice to JQuery and front-end development.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: How about starting from [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)?